# How to join my local PC to Google Kubernetes Engine cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, gpu, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to use Google Kubernetes Engine for my Deep Learning project (google cloud storage, docker, tensorflow, etc.).

I found that Google VM Instances with GPUs are expensive for this initial phase of the project. I would like to use my 3 home computers with GPUs. Is possible to join these local computers to Google Kubernetes Engine and to create hybrid cluster?

Thank you for any feedback or comment.

Comment: Suggestion: Create a Docker Swarm on your home networked computers - very easy. You could even create your own Kubernetes cluster, but that can be a challenge installing everything. Even with Google Anthos, I am not aware of a method to add your personal computers to a Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way could be to install a native K8s cluster on your 3 home computers. If you want to access data in GCP Persistent Disk or FileStore from the cluster, the CSI plugins should be also installed. These 2 repositories may help.

[filestore](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-filestore-csi-driver)

[persistent disk](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver)

Answer (score -1):

You can check out Anthos. It is a new product by Google made specifically for this

Comment: Google Anthos on-prem requires VMware vSphere.